# Can you include CiviCRM ID in exported fields?

Tags: contacts, export

Our administrator needs to export email addresses for households and individuals complete with CiviCRM ID so that an audit of imported data can be undertaken. However, CiviCRM ID isn't available in the select fields stage of contact export.
Is there any way to work around this?

Answer (score 6):

Hmm, I export this all the time.  Maybe it isn't named what you think it's named.  It's called "Internal Contact ID" in the pull down menu.

If you don't find this what version of Civi are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, our administrator found it as Internal Contact ID - just a little confusing when it is named differently when displayed!